# Can't stream stored audio or video using URL with Backendless

Tags: ios, parse-platform, video-streaming, audio-streaming, backendless

We are having the issue that audio and video files, stored on Backendless, are not streaming in our app.

With Parse shutting down, our company is currently migrating our projects from Parse to Backendless which provides a similar service. Our apps store many of our files as URLs so that users can access them without needing to store the information directly on their device.

Our currently code successfully plays audio and video messages from URLs stored in Parse which returns a URL in the following format:

```
http://files.parsetfss.com/132a89e7-8356-4a75-96e5-c02a5605f557/tfss-2a38997b-c2d9-4dbb-945b-9b19481adc62-audio.mp4
```

We have substituted in the new Backendless code which stores the files but doesn't allow them to be played:

```
https://api.backendless.com/fcc9c043-c20b-fffc-ffe0-6052ac639f00/v1/files/F4EA010F-9F2A-42CF-95BC-0C6F900B05CD-audio.mp4
```

If you copy either of these into the browser the audio file will be played meaning that we know the file has been uploaded correctly.

Considering the code already works with Parse URLs I don't feel that this is an issue with the code meaning there must be an issue with the URL headers. We have made sure that we have enabled permissions in our dashboard meaning that it isn't because we don't have permission to download and play. (these permissions are the same for all user types)

[image]

Is there any reason why a URL wouldn't play due to how it has been set up? How would someone change the headers to enable/disable streaming of the data?

Any help would be very appreciated